# jQuery event for a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to create a button with a event which occurs when a user clicked on it.
If someone has clicked this button a slider shows up.

I want a function if no one release this slider div the div toggles after 5 seconds, but if someone releases the slider nothing must happen!

I have created a fiddle in hope someone can fix this?
http://jsfiddle.net/84nVQ/50/

```
function handler1() {
    clearTimeout(time);
    $('#volumeChange').attr("class", "selected");
    $('#volume-slider').slider({
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        value: 100,
        max: 1,
        step: 0.01,
        animate: true,
        slide: function(e, ui) {
            alert(ui.value);
        }
    }).show();
}

function handler2() {
    time = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#volumeChange').attr("class", "");
        $('#volume-slider').toggle();
        $('#volume-slider').clearTimeout(time);
    }, 5000);
}

function handler3() {
    clearTimeout(time);
}


$("#volumeChange").on({
    click: function(e) {
        handler1();
        $('#volume-slider').mouseleave(handler2).mouseenter(handler3);
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to declare `time` somewhere outside those functions: `var time;` and also `$('#volume-slider').clearTimeout(time);` will give an error because jQuery doesn't have a `clearTimeout()` method - though you can just delete that line because clearing a timeout that has already happened doesn't do anything.

Comment: it doesnt not work proberly. View it on jsfiddle link post in question.

Answer (score 0):

There were two errors: undefined time variable and clearTimeout. This code should work

```
var time = null;

function handler1() {
    clearTimeout(time);
    $('#volumeChange').attr("class", "selected");
    $('#volume-slider').slider({
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        value: 100,
        max: 1,
        step: 0.01,
        animate: true,
        slide: function(e, ui) {
            movie.volume = ui.value;
        }
    }).show();
}

function handler2() {
    time = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#volumeChange').attr("class", "");
        $('#volume-slider').toggle();
        clearTimeout(time);
    }, 5000);
}

function handler3() {
    clearTimeout(time);
}


$("#volumeChange").on({
    click: function(e) {
        handler1();
        $('#volume-slider').mouseleave(handler2).mouseenter(handler3);
    }
});
```

Comment: You should be able to remove `clearTimeout(time);` from `handler2()` - it doesn't do anything given it is trying to clear the timeout currently executing (at which point it is too late to clear it).